# Scipy Minimize and np.linlag.norm

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

This is my first time posting a question here, so please bear with me. Now, I was "playing" with the minimize function and I came across something odd.

The set up is simple, all I want to do is to minimize the euclidian norm of the form:

sqrt[(x1 -a1)^2+(x2 -a2)^2+(x3 -a3)^2+(x4 -a4)^2]

Where x's are variables and a's are some fixed numbers, constants. Of course the solution is simple, xi=ai for i=1,2,3,4; and the value of the function is zero.

Now, when I do this code in python, everything works fine:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def w(x):
    a = np.array([[0,1,1,0]]).T
    return np.sqrt((x[0]-a[0])**2 + (x[1]-a[1])**2 + (x[2]-a[2])**2+(x[3]-a[3])**2)

np.random.seed(1)
x0 = np.random.random((4,1))

min_fun1 = minimize(w,x0,method='nelder-mead',options={'xatol': 1e-8, 'disp': True})
print(min_fun1.fun)
print(min_fun1.x)
```

As I said, this works just fine. The value of the function is zero and xi=ai. But, when I try to set up the problem using the np.linlag.norm function, it gets weird. For example, when I run this code:

```
def y(x):
    a = np.array([[0,1,1,0]]).T
    return np.linalg.norm(x-a)

min_fun0 = minimize(y,x0,method='nelder-mead',options={'xatol': 1e-8, 'disp': True})
min_fun0.fun
min_fun0.x
```

It seems like the optimization gets stuck, the value of the function is 2 and xi=0.5, which obviously it is not correct.

Even more, if I try to do it with the dot product, the result is different but still incorrect:

```
def v(x):
    a = np.array([[0,1,1,0]]).T

    return np.sqrt(np.dot((x-a).T,(x-a)))

min_fun2 = minimize(v,x0,method='nelder-mead',options={'xatol': 1e-8, 'disp': True})
min_fun2.fun
min_fun2.x
```

What I was able to understand is that it has something to do with the "type" of the object. For example, no.linalg.norm returns a float64 and for the example that works is ndarray with size 1. So, I change the "type" for no.linalg.norm result to match ndarray size 1, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to minimize a 1d array, but `np.array([[0,1,1,0]])` is actually 2d (shape is `(1, 4)`).

If you convert your array to 1d the minimisation seems to work:

```
def y(x):
    a = np.array([0,1,1,0])
    return np.linalg.norm(x-a)

min_fun0 = minimize(y,x0,method='nelder-mead',options={'xatol': 1e-8, 'disp': True})
min_fun0.fun
min_fun0.x
>>> array([-1.87741758e-09,  1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00, -3.04858536e-09])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works perfectly... jajaja the solution was so simple. I was stuck with this for a long time, it is embarrasing. Again, thank you.

Comment: Glad to help! Worth using the `.ravel()` method if you think the arrays should be 1d, just to make sure.

Comment: @Rodrigo Consider accepting the answer as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)